# Migrating from Google's deprecated jsapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsapi, markitup

I have and old website that I am now managing but haven't coded myself. The developer has integrated version 1.5.1 of jQuery with the following code from google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.5.1");</script>
```

The console is being flooded with the following error message about c.replace is not a function and also that loading modules from jsapi is deprecated. Sometimes the entire jQuery library is not loaded and the page needs to be refreshed.
[https://i.imgur.com/UrXvqzM.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUf3t.png)

I tried integrating version 1.5.1 of jQuery with a cdn that is given in the console (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js) as well as from from [cloudflare](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js), however because the website is using the [MarkItUp](https://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) plugin, there is something missing and MarkItUp isn't working. It's quite old, I know, but I can't just move to another editor. I don't know if google.load function is loading more files than just regular jQuery but I don't know how I can troubleshoot the problem and see what is missing. So, if anyone has an idea how to migrate from jsapi and load the correct jQuery version, I will much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just comment the two lines and add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Choose here an existing version:
[Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery)